# Which group sold the most percentage wise

Tags: statistics

We have 10 groups of people.  Each group membership varies from 5 to 35.  Each group is tasked with selling cookies.  How do I calculate each groups' sales percentage?  For example:

Group 1 has 5 people and sold 20 cookies
Group 2 has 10 people and sold 20 cookies
Group 3 has 6 people and sold 15 cookies

Which group sold the highest percentage of cookies as it relates to group membership?  I want them all on an even scale.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to rank the groups in terms of cookies sold per member? If that is the case, just divide the number of cookies the group sold by the number of people in it.

Comment: It also depends if the costumer is lactose-intolerant or not.

Answer (score 0):

Most level way to do this would simply be to calculate the average number of cookies sold per member. In other words, divide the # of cookies sold by the number of members.